# How can I internationalize meta og tags to be parsed correctly by Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, grails, facebook-opengraph

I have a grails application with meta og tags like this:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="${message(code:'description')}"/>
```

The message properties works fine for i18n if the user's browser send the request. But in case of Facebook it is different. Facebook seems to request alwas the en_US version on my page which means that the meta og tags are always in the wrong language if the user requests the page from a de_DE browser.

Is there a way to tell facebook to use a different request language than en_US?

I tried:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="de_DE" />
```

but this does not change the requested language as well.

What can I do to get the correct i18n?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you setup some `og:locale:alternate` meta tag, Facebook will rescrape the page by passing a `get` parameter `fb_locale` with the value of the locale. For example, if your site is `http://mysite.com/share` and it present these alternative locales:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES" />
    ...
</head>
    ...
</html>
```

Facebook will call these url on your site.

```
http://mysite.com/share
http://mysite.com/share?fb_locale=fr_FR
http://mysite.com/share?fb_locale=es_ES
```

You then just need to localize you content (and set `og:locale`) correctly.

Doc is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/internationalization/

Comment: what is the difference between og:locale and og:locale:alternate?

Comment: `og:locale` is the current locale (e.g.: in which language the og tags are written). `og:locale:alternate` are alternative locales that Facebook will fetch using `?fb_locale=your_LOCALE`.

Comment: so when I want my page to be grapped in German I have to put <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="de_DE" /> on my page?

Comment: Yes, and then, Facebook will send a request to `http://yoursite.com/share?fb_locale=de_DE`, and then, on this page you put all text in german, and you add `<meta property="og:locale" content="de_DE">`